# Targeting mobile menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to target css to the mobile menu only? I am using http://athemes.com/theme/Sydney and my dev server is at http://150.101.201.63/wordpress2/WordPress/
Simply put when the menu changes to the mobile menu (one with single button to open menu versus top navigation menu) I want to add some styling. I used to do this by device width but I'm finding this less effective with this theme.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resize your desktop window to actuate the mobile display of your site and use a web inspector tool in your browser to find the element you'd like to change.
Your Dev site is broken, but Renovation Princess uses the element #respo-menu-list-left to effect portions of your mobile menu.

Answer (score 0):

I tried/guessed it and the url is http://150.101.201.63/wordpress2/wordpress/, so now uppercase in wordpress.

I looked in over the website and when it displays the mobile menu it changes the menu id to `mainnav-mobi`, so you can safely write you css for that id and it will only show on mobile.

```
#mainnav-mobi {
  /* css here */
}
```